# Blank space after hide virtual buttons using Expo

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm creating new react-native project (using create-react-native-app) and I have problem with blank space below bottomTabNavigation after hiding virtual buttons.
When I use development mode (expo,QR code etc) everything works as it should. The problem occure after build .apk file.
The best explanation will be screenshots

Before hide virtual buttons:
[image]

And after hide virtual buttons:
[image]

It leaves blank space below the tab navigation. It is worth noting that problem occured ONLY after building .apk file. While development using Expo it works good.

Comment: You can change navigation bar `let navibarHeight = Dimensions.get('screen').height;`

Comment: @hongdevelop Ok, this is how I can get navibarHeight, but where should I set this value?

Comment: You can set it to the vertical height of your screen.

Comment: styles's `height: navibarHeight `

Comment: @hongdevelop Still I dont know place where should i set this. What does it mean "height of your screen"? Which component? 
This is piece of the code in App.js
`return (
      <AppLoading
        startAsync={loadResourcesAsync}
        onError={handleLoadingError}
        onFinish={() => handleFinishLoading(setLoadingComplete)}
      />
    );
  } else {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        {<StatusBar style={{backgroundColor: Colors.BLUE}} />}
        <AppNavigator />
      </View>
    );
  }`

Comment: Please correct the questions for the overall code and post them. It's hard to recognize.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/8B8H8iSZ

Comment: The screen that needs to be applied is the screen height that AppNavigator will display.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/j6UN1AyF
you mean each screen  (SomeScreen, Some1Screen ...) 
should be styled?

Comment: that's right. You can specify the height of the parent on the screen.